# How can I merge these two dataframes correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

there, I have two data frames like in the following table

First is df_zero_purchase: Includes around 4700 rows.

| OrderItemSKU | PurchasePrice | TotalWeight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4188-DE | 0.0 | 2.5 |
| 5300-MY | 0.0 | 3.8 |
| 1889-XC | 0.0 | 4.7 |

```py
df_zero_purchase =  pd.DataFrame({
  "OrderItemSKU": ['4188-DE', '5300-MY', '1889-XC'],
  "PurchasePrice": [0, 0, 0],
  "TotalWeight":[2.5, 3.8, 4.5]
})
```

And the second is df_purchase: Includes 4814 rows.

| OrderItemSKU | PurchasePrice |
| --- | --- |
| 4188-DE | 5.5 |
| 5300-MY | 8.3 |
| 1889-XC | 2.1 |

```
df_purchase = pd.DataFrame({
  "OrderItemSKU": ['4188-DE', '5300-MY', '1889-XC'],
  "PurchasePrice": [5.5, 8.3, 2.1],
})
```

I just wanted to update the zero PurchasePrices on my first data frame .I tried the following code but at the and it gives as shape with almost 50000 rows. I don't understand why ? So I need your help...

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_zero_purchase, df_purchase[['OrderItemSKU', 'PurchasePrice']], on='ORDERITEMSKU')
```

Comment: Do you have duplicated merging keys?

Comment: If you mean OrderItemSKU and PurchasePrices, they are both same on both tables.

Comment: No, I meant, what is the output of `df_zero_purchase['OrderItemSKU'].duplicated().sum()`? And same for `df_purchase`.

Comment: df_zero_purchase['OrderItemSKU'].duplicated().sum() ---- 4222
df_purchase['OrderItemSKU'].duplicated().sum() ----- 4238

Comment: That's why. If you have duplicated merging keys, you'll get the combinations in the merge

Comment: what should I do to solve it ?

Comment: You should decide on how you want to aggregate the data during the merge. Please update the example to include duplicated keys and provide the expected output

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), where `df1` and `df2` are, respectively, the first and the second dataframes:

```
df1['PurchasePrice'].update(df2['PurchasePrice'])
```

---

In case the dataframes are not in the same order, we can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='OrderItemSKU', suffixes=('_','')).iloc[:, [0,3,2]]
```

Or again [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), but setting `OrderItemSKU` as index in both dataframes:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('OrderItemSKU')
df1.update(df2.set_index('OrderItemSKU'))
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

---

Output:

```
  OrderItemSKU  PurchasePrice  TotalWeight
0      4188-DE            5.5          2.5
1      5300-MY            8.3          3.8
2      1889-XC            2.1          4.7
```

Comment: Thanks for it but there are lots of different values and not in the same order :))

Answer (score 0):

You must have duplicate values for "OrderItemSKU" column. Please remove duplicate from both dataframe. and then try to merge.

Use df[df.duplicated('OrderItemSKU')], for both dataframe.
If you want to remove duplicate use -
new_df = df[df.duplicated(keep = 'first')]

Comment: Could you please explain or code it I could't get you exactly ?

Comment: step 1 -new_df_zero_purchase = df_zero_purchase[df_zero_purchase.duplicated(keep = 'first')]  then 
step2-new_df_purchase = df_purchase[df_purchase.duplicated(keep = 'first')] then 
step3-df_merged = pd.merge(new_df_zero_purchase, new_df_purchase[['OrderItemSKU', 'PurchasePrice']], on='ORDERITEMSKU')